# python dbus method for watching a directory change?

Tags: python, dbus, inotify

I have successfully used the python bindings to `io_add_watch` in my dbus mainloop to react to changes in a known single file. But I have a case now, where I'm running a dbus mainloop, and need to do work when a directory changes.

I've played around with the command line tool `inotifywait -m directory`, as well as played with some of the examples provided with pyinotify. What's unclear is how I put the two together. Or if I even should. I *could* just launch a thread that uses a pipe to run `inotifywait` directly, and then write to a ram file in `/run` which I had established an `io_add_watch` to. I'm relatively new to glib/dbus/mainloop, so it's still kind of magic to me. `pyinotify` seems kind of heavy for my purposes, but I'm working from no experience here.

I'm running on Debian Jessie, using python3. I am not looking for anything cross platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInotify can easily watch a directory:

```
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
wm.add_watch('/tmp', pyinotify.IN_CREATE)
notifier.loop()
```

The full tutorial is here: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial#1-using-the-notifier-class-without-timeout

Comment: This was nominally helpful, and I eventually figured it out, see the answer I added. I wish it would have been more like that, but you get the creds for getting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In particular to weave the notify stuff in with a dbus loop, the trick was to use a `ThreadedNotifier` from `pyinotify`. I used something like this:

```
watchManager = pyinotify.WatchManager()
inotifier = pyinotify.ThreadedNotifier(watchManager, FileEventHandler(mainService.eventStream))
inotifier.start()
eventsPath = Path('/Pilot/Schedules')
if not eventsPath.exists():
    eventsPath.mkdir()
watchManager.add_watch(eventsPath.as_posix(), pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE | pyinotify.IN_DELETE, rec=True, auto_add=True)

mainloop = glib.MainLoop()
try:
    mainloop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    mainloop.quit()
    inotifier.stop()
```

My `FileEventHandler` used the standard methods such as `process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE` to then submit dbus changes.